# The background color of code blocks (syntax highlighting) do not change when I change the chroma style

Tags: codeblocks, syntax-highlighting, hugo

Following [this](https://adityatelange.github.io/hugo-PaperMod/posts/papermod/papermod-faq/#using-hugos-syntax-highlighter-chroma), I am trying to change the "style" in config.yml of the syntax highlighting by changing the style (e.g. abap, colorful like [here](https://xyproto.github.io/splash/docs/all.html) from the default (monokai)), but only the color of font changes and the background color in code block does not change (the color is always black like monokai).
Do I miss something? Could anyone kindly tell me what is wrong?

I am using the following setting.

```yaml
params:
    assets:
        disableHLJS: true

markup:
    goldmark:
        renderer:
            unsafe: true
    highlight:
        #anchorLineNos: true
        codeFences: true
        guessSyntax: true
        lineNos: false
        #noClasses: false
        style: abap
```